# Consuming a third party RESTful API passing a parameter

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc

I need to consume a third party RESTful API. This is my controller class:

```java
@Controller
public class BrokerController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/broker", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody MyPojo brokers(@RequestBody BrokerRequest brokerRequest){

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        final String uri = "http://www.nepalipaisa.com/Modules/MarketMovers/Services/MarketMoversServices.asmx/GetTopBrokers";

        MyPojo myPojo = restTemplate.postForObject(uri,brokerRequest,MyPojo.class);
        return myPojo;
    }

}
```

Edited:- My pojo class:

```
public class MyPojo {
private String __type;
private Integer RowTotal;
private Integer StockID;
private Object CodedCompany;
private Object ClosingPrice;
private Integer Amount;
private Integer PreviousClosing;
private Integer DifferenceRS;
private Object Symbol;
private Integer Price;
private Integer Diff;
private Integer PercentageDiff;
private Object Volume;
private Integer TotalTurnOverAmount;
private String FirmName;
private Integer BrokerID;
private String BrokerCode;
private Integer TotalTransactions;
private Object Traded;
private Object MaxPrice;
private Object MinPrice;
private Object OpeningPrice;
private Object TotalShare;
private Integer NoOfTransaction;
private Integer Purchase;
private Integer Sales;
private Integer Matching;


public String get__type() {
    return __type;
}

public void set__type(String __type) {
    this.__type = __type;
}

public Integer getRowTotal() {
    return RowTotal;
}

public void setRowTotal(Integer rowTotal) {
    this.RowTotal = rowTotal;
}

public Integer getStockID() {
    return StockID;
}

public void setStockID(Integer stockID) {
    this.StockID = stockID;
}

public Object getCodedCompany() {
    return CodedCompany;
}

public void setCodedCompany(Object codedCompany) {
    this.CodedCompany = codedCompany;
}

public Object getClosingPrice() {
    return ClosingPrice;
}

public void setClosingPrice(Object closingPrice) {
    this.ClosingPrice = closingPrice;
}

public Integer getAmount() {
    return Amount;
}

public void setAmount(Integer amount) {
    this.Amount = amount;
}

public Integer getPreviousClosing() {
    return PreviousClosing;
}

public void setPreviousClosing(Integer previousClosing) {
    this.PreviousClosing = previousClosing;
}

public Integer getDifferenceRS() {
    return DifferenceRS;
}

public void setDifferenceRS(Integer differenceRS) {
    this.DifferenceRS = differenceRS;
}

public Object getSymbol() {
    return Symbol;
}

public void setSymbol(Object symbol) {
    this.Symbol = symbol;
}

public Integer getPrice() {
    return Price;
}

public void setPrice(Integer price) {
    this.Price = price;
}

public Integer getDiff() {
    return Diff;
}

public void setDiff(Integer diff) {
    this.Diff = diff;
}

public Integer getPercentageDiff() {
    return PercentageDiff;
}

public void setPercentageDiff(Integer percentageDiff) {
    this.PercentageDiff = percentageDiff;
}

public Object getVolume() {
    return Volume;
}

public void setVolume(Object volume) {
    this.Volume = volume;
}

public Integer getTotalTurnOverAmount() {
    return TotalTurnOverAmount;
}

public void setTotalTurnOverAmount(Integer totalTurnOverAmount) {
    this.TotalTurnOverAmount = totalTurnOverAmount;
}

public String getFirmName() {
    return FirmName;
}

public void setFirmName(String firmName) {
    this.FirmName = firmName;
}

public Integer getBrokerID() {
    return BrokerID;
}

public void setBrokerID(Integer brokerID) {
    this.BrokerID = brokerID;
}

public String getBrokerCode() {
    return BrokerCode;
}

public void setBrokerCode(String brokerCode) {
    this.BrokerCode = brokerCode;
}

public Integer getTotalTransactions() {
    return TotalTransactions;
}

public void setTotalTransactions(Integer totalTransactions) {
    this.TotalTransactions = totalTransactions;
}

public Object getTraded() {
    return Traded;
}

public void setTraded(Object traded) {
    this.Traded = traded;
}

public Object getMaxPrice() {
    return MaxPrice;
}

public void setMaxPrice(Object maxPrice) {
    this.MaxPrice = maxPrice;
}

public Object getMinPrice() {
    return MinPrice;
}

public void setMinPrice(Object minPrice) {
    this.MinPrice = minPrice;
}

public Object getOpeningPrice() {
    return OpeningPrice;
}

public void setOpeningPrice(Object openingPrice) {
    this.OpeningPrice = openingPrice;
}

public Object getTotalShare() {
    return TotalShare;
}

public void setTotalShare(Object totalShare) {
    this.TotalShare = totalShare;
}

public Integer getNoOfTransaction() {
    return NoOfTransaction;
}

public void setNoOfTransaction(Integer noOfTransaction) {
    this.NoOfTransaction = noOfTransaction;
}

public Integer getPurchase() {
    return Purchase;
}

public void setPurchase(Integer purchase) {
    this.Purchase = purchase;
}

public Integer getSales() {
    return Sales;
}

public void setSales(Integer sales) {
    this.Sales = sales;
}

public Integer getMatching() {
    return Matching;
}

public void setMatching(Integer matching) {
    this.Matching = matching;
}
}
```

The JSON iI need to consume, i.e the exact result given below:

```
{
"d": [
    {
        "__type": "SageFrame.MarketMovers.MarketInfo",
        "RowTotal": 0,
        "StockID": 0,
        "CodedCompany": null,
        "ClosingPrice": null,
        "Amount": 0,
        "PreviousClosing": 0,
        "DifferenceRS": 0,
        "Symbol": null,
        "Price": 0,
        "Diff": 0,
        "PercentageDiff": 0,
        "Volume": null,
        "TotalTurnOverAmount": 109969058,
        "FirmName": "Vision Securities Pvt. Ltd.",
        "BrokerID": 0,
        "BrokerCode": "34",
        "TotalTransactions": 0,
        "Traded": null,
        "MaxPrice": null,
        "MinPrice": null,
        "OpeningPrice": null,
        "TotalShare": null,
        "NoOfTransaction": 0,
        "Purchase": 70691939,
        "Sales": 39277119,
        "Matching": 6381555
    },
    {
        "__type": "SageFrame.MarketMovers.MarketInfo",
        "RowTotal": 0,
        "StockID": 0,
        "CodedCompany": null,
        "ClosingPrice": null,
        "Amount": 0,
        "PreviousClosing": 0,
        "DifferenceRS": 0,
        "Symbol": null,
        "Price": 0,
        "Diff": 0,
        "PercentageDiff": 0,
        "Volume": null,
        "TotalTurnOverAmount": 104830489,
        "FirmName": "Online Securities Pvt. Ltd.",
        "BrokerID": 0,
        "BrokerCode": "49",
        "TotalTransactions": 0,
        "Traded": null,
        "MaxPrice": null,
        "MinPrice": null,
        "OpeningPrice": null,
        "TotalShare": null,
        "NoOfTransaction": 0,
        "Purchase": 51927902,
        "Sales": 52902587,
        "Matching": 3049044
    }
]
}
```

Currently when I send a POST request with two parameters

```
{
    "offset":"1",
    "limit":"2000"
}
```

I can get the result given above. Now I need to return the same result but through my own controller. The above controller returns `MyPojo` class with `null` value on every properties.

Comment: Are you saying that your MyPojo does not match exactly to the JSON the third party API is returning?

Comment: MyPojo myPojo = restTemplate.postForObject(uri,brokerRequest,MyPojo.class);

this line of code won't return any value.

Comment: Maybe because your third party api is returning another data format. Maybe xml.

Comment: nope. i have given above the sample of how third party rest api returns data. look above please.

Comment: That api is actually returning `xml`.

Comment: can you please explain how it is returning xml cause when i request from postman it returns json.

Comment: @AbdullahWasi Maybe the RestTemplate uses application/json as the content type, hence it comes back as json.

Comment: @josemartinez correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try to put the results from the third party API into a Map.

```
Map results = restTemplate.postForObject(uri,brokerRequest, Map.class);
```

Or you can create a new pojo just for that third part API.

```
ThirdPartyPojo results = restTemplate.postForObject(uri,brokerRequest, ThirdPartyPojo.class);
```

Comment: yes i have done like you said in second option. but it returns null values for all the properties like this:-

Comment: {
    "__type": null,
    "symbol": null,
    "sales": null,
    "totalTransactions": null,
    "previousClosing": null,
    "diff": null,
    "traded": null,
    "closingPrice": null ....
}

Comment: Have you tried a Map?  With a map it just uses whatever values are int he response from the third party API.  If after using a Map the fields are still null, then that means their value is null coming from the third party API.

Answer (score 1):

Right now the issue is that your pojo `MyPojo` is not compatible with the response of 3rd party API.

Your pojo should be something like following.

-----------------------------------com.example.D.java-----------------------------------

```
package com.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

public class D {

private String type;
private Integer rowTotal;
private Integer stockID;
private Object codedCompany;
private Object closingPrice;
private Integer amount;
private Integer previousClosing;
private Integer differenceRS;
private Object symbol;
private Integer price;
private Integer diff;
private Integer percentageDiff;
private Object volume;
private Integer totalTurnOverAmount;
private String firmName;
private Integer brokerID;
private String brokerCode;
private Integer totalTransactions;
private Object traded;
private Object maxPrice;
private Object minPrice;
private Object openingPrice;
private Object totalShare;
private Integer noOfTransaction;
private Integer purchase;
private Integer sales;
private Integer matching;

// Getter .. Setter//
}
```

-----------------------------------com.example.MyPojo.java-----------------------------------

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

public class Example {

@JsonProperty("d")
private List<D> d = null;

// Getter ... Setter
}
```

Or simply you can use Map.

Comment: I tried this on my local machine. The properties like `firmName` are still null.

Comment: The possible issue can be getter setter method name might be incorrect. can you verify that ?

Comment: and here i am still getting null.

Comment: @Pratik you got your answer!

Comment: @sagarlimbu : after doing the suggested you are still getting null ?? can you update the question with the new pojo ?

Comment: @Pratik can you test the api that's been hit? Please let me know what format you are getting?

Comment: @AbdullahWasi : http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=a6e3f2a355e466728ddd2106fe6fc4f0 I am getting json from postman

Comment: please see the edited pojo. and i'm still getting null values.

Comment: Your pojo are still incorrect. just look at my answer properly. See that in MyPojo there should be only single field List<D> & D.java contains all the fields. Please correct them.

Answer (score 1):

---

This can be accomplished easily not even requiring you to provide custom mappings or whatever like that and guarantee that your controller wil provide the same response (not the same headers, though):

```java
@RestController
final class Controller {

    // Both RestTemplate and URI instances can be cached
    private static final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private static final URI testUri = URI.create("http://www.nepalipaisa.com/Modules/MarketMovers/Services/MarketMoversServices.asmx/GetTopBrokers");

    // I'm using GET just to simplify the testing using a web browser
    @RequestMapping(method = GET, value = "/")
    public void post(final ServletResponse response)
            throws IOException {
        // Create a POST request entity
        final RequestEntity<?> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(getRequest(0, 10), POST, testUri);
        // And send the request to the remote server
        final ResponseEntity<Resource> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, Resource.class);
        // Now just copy the response input stream to the output stream of this controller
        try ( final InputStream inputStream = responseEntity.getBody().getInputStream() ) {
            // Or provide HttpServletResponse via the controller method to be able to configure the response more accurately
            StreamUtils.copy(inputStream, response.getOutputStream());
        }
    }

    private static Object getRequest(final long offset, final long limit) {
        final Map<String, Object> request = new HashMap<>();
        request.put("offset", offset);
        request.put("limit", limit);
        return request;
    }

}
```

The remote server can respond with a non-successful response code, so you can also have a custom controller advice to handle `RestTemplate` exceptions:

```java
@ControllerAdvice
final class ExceptionControllerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(HttpServerErrorException.class)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<?> handleHttpServerErrorException(final HttpServerErrorException ex) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>("Bad gateway: " + ex.getMessage(), BAD_GATEWAY);
    }

}
```